# Facebook API - Can't find specific places

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to look for a place ID with facebook API. My code works for most of the places pages/locations, but there are some specific places I can't find in the facebook graph API in any way.

Why there are places that are not listed on the facebook graph API and impossible to find? Is there any way or filter key to make them show up or find their place ID?

[Example](https://www.facebook.com/bootleg.telaviv?fref=ts) of such a place.
[Example](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=bootleg&type=place&limit=50&fields=name,location&access_token=XXX) of a query I used to find this page.

Comment: What kind of access token are you using – app or user? If the page you are looking for is restricted in any way (alcohol-related content, age, location) – then you need to use a user access token of a user that can “see” them.

Comment: My website is "places" search engine so I am using app token. User token will ruin the idea of "1 click search" and will force the user to login into the website. Does google api provides something better?

Comment: In addition, I tried to add &user_token=mytoken to the search api as parameter, and the place still not shown up.

Comment: You're search is too broad. You should be specifying 'center' coordinates and 'distance' to narrow down your search.